# Remove <span> when text is clicked

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<span class="deleted typo" id="typo1" contenteditable="false"> innovation via workplace diversity</span>
```

I need to remove the `<span>` element without removing the inside text when I click on the text itself, and it needs to be only on this element, not others with the same class. Is this possible with jQuery?

Comment: $("#yourSpanId").remove();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$('#typo1').click(function() {

  $(this).contents().unwrap("<span></span>");

})
```

```css
.deleted{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="deleted typo" id="typo1" contenteditable="false"> innovation via workplace diversity</span>
```

Use `.contents()` together with `.unwrap()`

[.contents()](https://api.jquery.com/contents/)

> Description: Get the children of each element in the set of matched elements, including text and comment nodes.

[.unwrap()](https://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

> Description: Remove the parents of the set of matched elements from the DOM, leaving the matched elements in their place.

Comment: Just an additional thought: this works, but only on content pre-existing content. For dynamic content, you would have to use 
`$(document).on('click', '.typo', function () {`

Answer (score 0):

Try this using jquery

```
<script    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#typo1").click(function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 <span class="deleted typo" id="typo1" contenteditable="false"> <p>innovation via workplace diversity</p></span>


 $("#typo1").click(function(){
        $("p").unwrap();
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun and a didactic way, without any lib, this is **a pure javascript solution**.

```js
document.getElementById('typo1').addEventListener('click', function() {
  var mySpan = document.getElementById('typo1');
  var parentNode = mySpan.parentNode ;
  while (mySpan.firstChild) parentNode.insertBefore(mySpan.firstChild, mySpan);
  mySpan.parentNode.removeChild(mySpan);

});
```

```html
<span class="deleted typo" id="typo1" contenteditable="false"> innovation via workplace diversity</span>
```

Comment: This deletes the text along with the element.

Comment: You're true, I misread the question, and I updated my snippet. Now it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is this:

```
$('#typo1').click(function() {

   // get the text
   var t = $(this).text();

   // get the parent to add the text after removing the span
   var p = $(this).parent()

   // remove the span
   $(this).remove();

   // set the text back to parent
   p.text(t);

   // if the parent has more controls you may have to append
   // p.append(t);

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/tedmanowar/ykb1px05/

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I found. `.unwrap()` won't work because that removes the parent element of the selector, not the element around the text node. You have to replace `this` with the `childNodes`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".typo").click(function(){
        $(this).replaceWith(this.childNodes);
    });
});
```

Comment: happy coding mate